# Metric on bounded sequences that induces pointwise convergence

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

I got the following question in my functional analysis course.
let B($\mathbb{N}$) be the linear space of bounded functions $f:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ (i.e bounded sequences). Find a metric d that induces pointwise convergence (i.e $f_n$ converges pointwise to $f$ iff $f_n$ converges to $f$ in the metric d).

I tried to use both the supremum and discrete metrics, alas I found sequences which converge pointwise but dont converge in the metric.
I also tried to define metrics using lim sup / lim inf since the sequences are bounded but alas they aren't metrices ($d(f,g)$ = $0$ for two different functions).

any help would be appreciated

Comment: You can think of this as an extension of the finite case, which is $\mathbb{R}^k$. In that case, a metric like
$$\sum_{i=1}^k |x_i-y_i|$$
works. The problem is this doesn't converge in the countable case. Can you think of a way to modify it to make it converge?

Comment: thank you! I think I can define d(f,g) = $\sum_{x=1}^\infty\frac{|f(x)-g(x)|}{x^2}$
 and I managed to show that if f converges to g under that metric it also converges to g pointwise, but I failed to to show that if f converges to g pointwise it also converges to g in the metric. may I ask for another hint?

Comment: So, I made a mistake. That is what I was thinking of when I gave that hint, but it doesn't quite work. In fact, no norm-induced metric can work  because if $z_n = \frac{e_n}{|e_n|}$ then $|z_n|=1$ even though $z_n \to 0$ pointwise. However, there is a variation on this which does work. The problem here is that you can keep making the 'tail' bigger and bigger while the first $n$ terms converge, so that the sequence converges pointwise while still being a large distance away in that norm. Can you think of a modification that puts a cap on how big the tail can be?

Comment: the modification will of course have to break absolute homogeneity, as the answer can't be a norm

Comment: I tried to change it a little by defining $d(f,g) = \sum_{x=1}^\infty\frac{|f(x)-g(x)|}{2^x}$
but I still run into the sequence
$$f_{n}\left(x\right)=\begin{cases}
2^n & x=n\\
0 & else
\end{cases}$$
which converges pointwise to 0 but for every $n\in\mathbb{N}$ we have d($f_n$,0) = 1 so it doesn't converge under the metric.

I'm not sure how to limit the tail further and I'm not sure how to break homogeneity

Comment: You can turn any metric into a bounded metric by capping it at (e.g.) $1$. If $d$ is a metrics then $d'(x,y) = \min\{d(x,y),1\}$ is a metric. If you apply this to each individual term in the sequence, then you know that the tail of
$$\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} a_i\min\{|x_i|,1\}$$
starting at $m$ can be at most
$$\sum_{i=m}^{\infty} a_i$$

Comment: thank you very much!